# Is this all there is? Tiny Death Star

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I'm playing Tiny Death Star but have all the available levels and nothing new has come up for months. I'm just collecting money and hit the 6 million Mark but I can't spend it on anything. Am I finished? Is it over? Am I the only one with this problem?